# f:convertDateTime in xhtml nested in a component?

Tags: jakarta-ee, date, xhtml

it was my understanding that this piece of code :

```
<composite:implementation>
    <p:fieldset>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{amsg.possibleTraining}"/>
                <h:outputText value=" #{cc.attrs.offer.workOfferedFrom}">
                    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                </h:outputText>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </p:fieldset>
```

should give me a "normal" date, but the page is displaying something like :
"Sat Jun 01 00:00:00 CEST 2013"
still.
Anybody has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!